# CSS Position element on bottom of container without removing it from flow

Tags: css, layout, sticky-footer

I have a container with 3 children elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <img />
  <div class="element1"></div>
  <div class="element2 bottom"></div>
</div>
```

They must be positioned as shown on the diagram below:

- *image* is in the top of the left column and nothing goes below it (it is the only element in the left column)
- *element1* is in the top of the right column
- *element2* is stick to the bottom of the right column (and must not collide with the *element1* which is above it)

[image]

**Does somebody know how to achieve such layout using pure CSS? Ideally I wouldn't like to add any markup, but I can do that if that's the only possible way.**

The biggest problem I'm facing here is how to stick that second element (non-image) to the bottom of the container without removing it from the flow. Because if I use `position: absolute` and remove it from the flow, the elment above it can collide with it (both elements have unknown height).

**Here's a pen to work on:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNwGvQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **two columns** in your *html* and then use the property `display: flex;` for your right column as suggested in the article [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

http://codepen.io/AlexisBertin/pen/QboYyY

All the **HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column-left">
    <div class="image">This is an image</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-right">
    <div class="element1">This container has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change.<br/><br/> Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger.</div>
    <div class="element2">This container also has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Part of this **CSS**:

```
.column {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
.column.column-left { width: 100px; }
.column.column-right { 
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Hope you get the idea. Good Luck'.

**EDIT:**

The easiest way to achieve this without declaring `height` to the container seems to only create a third parent `div` to the **first block of the second column** and define it as `flex: 1;` while the **second block of this same second column** would be define as `flex: 0;`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNwZmJ

*More details explained in the comments.*

Comment: Good idea! I forgot that I could align elements on vertical axis using Flexbox. That must work. Thank you.

Comment: It seems the bottom element2 isn't really stuck to the bottom. See this case: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QboYpP

Comment: It seems the *container* really needs a `height`. I'm looking forward.

Comment: Alright. It might be a good direction (I haven't thought about it myself), but I also don't know how to stick an element to one end of the axis inside a flex container.

Comment: The only way that I found out is to declare the *.column-right* as `position: absolute;` so in take all the *.container* `height`. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Now it doesn't work in the opposite case:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVqdQr : P. The outer container doesn't grow larger when the right column gets larger than left.

Comment: I managed to do it after adding one more <div>. The key was to add `flex: 1` on first element and `flex: 0` on the second, so that the first would take all the remaining space if needed. It looks totally ugly for me to add so much markup, but it seems that it's unavoidable here. Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNwZmJ. You can edit your answer in a similar manner and I'll accept it. You deserve it, as it was you who put me in the right direction.

Comment: Well ok, I was ready to suggest you to make your own answer and accept it if you would find the way to do it, to help to future readers, but fair enough. Thanks. : )

Comment: But indeed, that's very *tricky* and there is probably an easier way to do it in that kind of "simple environment". For a big layout with more blocks, I think it's legit to find a more *stable* way (as far as it's not easily breakable), even if it needs more markups.

Comment: What do you mean by *more stable* way? I think this solution could still scale to some bigger layouts. I'd only welcome with arms open a solution that wouldn't require adding so many non-semantic containers. I personally hate doing that : ).

Comment: Sorry, misunderstanding. By *stable* I mean a solution which still works even if the elements change, like yours with `flex: 1;` & `flex: 0;`. I can understand that fairly well as I'm pretty much the same.

Comment: Okay, so everything's clear now. Thanks once more for working out the solution with me. And have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I figured out is this one:

First you create this CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: white;
}
.container > img {
  float: left;
}
.container > div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  min-height: 120px; 
}
.container > div > .bottom{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

And then use these divs, depending on your content. The first one you use when you know your text is short:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This container has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>This container also has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second one you use when you know your text is long

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This container has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change.</p>
      <p>Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger. Some random content to make it larger.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>This container also has dynamic content so it's height is unknown and may change</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference is that you remove `bottom` class from the last div in your div that has long text.

Also in your CSS you can see `.container > div{... min-height: 120px; ...`}, you should set it to height of your image. In case you want the bottom text more down then you have to increase min-height to be bigger than your image height.

Here is it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXgBXx

Comment: This is only a partial solution. I mean breaking it into 2 cases is not a solution that I wanted and it's not that easy to implement. Still thanks for trying.